# Autohotkey if in clipboard

Tags: autohotkey

So I am trying to look for a specific text on the webpage and do a thing if the text was found, here is my current script:

```
!m::
clipboard =  
text = my text here
Send, {Ctrl}+A
Sleep, 100
Send, {Ctrl}+C
var1 = %clipboard%
IfInString, var1, %text%
msgbox found the text
else
msgbox no text found
```

And regardless if the text is on the webpage or not, it always returns "no text found"

Any help on this?

P.S. I've also tried "if contains" and removing line breaks from the variable but the result is the same :(

```
StringReplace, var1, var1, `r `n, All
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The send commands are not correct.

A command `{Ctrl}+A`, will press `Ctrl`, release it, and then press `A`. The lower case letter should also be used.

You should use either:

```
Send, {Ctrl down}{a}{Ctrl up}
```

or

```
Send, ^{a}
```

Do this for both Send commands.

A return commend should also be included as the end of the hotkey code 
sequence:

```
    ...
    else
    msgbox no text found
return
```

Comment: My bad, actually if I remove the second Send completely and just go with:

Send, {Ctrl down}{a}{c}{Ctrl up} 

Now works, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
!m::
clipboard := "", MyText := "Hello World"
cmds := ["{Ctrl down}", "a", "c", "{ctrl up}"]
Loop % cmds.MaxIndex() {
    Send % cmds[A_Index]
    if (A_index == 2)
        sleep 100
}
MsgBox % clipboard ~= "i)" MyText ? "Found" : "Not Found"
```